# Mask the map with a mapbox gl circle layer

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to mask the whole map using a Mapbox GL Circle Layer? I cant find any examples or useful links.

[I was able to add a mask layer using Mapbox GL GeoJSON layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bffbQ.png)

Comment: Could you share how you were able to mask the GeoJSON layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this in GL JS.

I recommend creating the circle mask in GeoJSON. [`turf-circle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-circle) should make this relatively easy.